# Images don't display inline

Tags: html, css, image, drupal, inline

My problem is that the images I want to be displayed inline, are displayed in a list form. I don't know what am I doing wrong, because in my opinion everything is correct.

## html

```
<div class="loga">
<img style="display:inline;" src="photos/logoWUT_czarne.PNG" width="370" height="135">
<img style="display:inline;" src="photos/bosch_logo_gray.png" height="115" width="380" >
<img style="display:inline;" src="photos/general-electric-logo-png_gray.png" height="115" width="115" >
</div>
```

## CSS

```
.loga {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

There must be something wrong with my code, because it does not work in any browser.

Comment: You have to reduce the width of an images to fit the container.

Comment: Otherwise, you can float your content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that it is a Drupal "feature" to add `<br>` tags at each end of the line, even in the "Full HTML" mode. To disable it you have to go to Admin>Configuration>Input Formats, select "configure" to the right of "Full HTML", and uncheck the box labeled "Line break converter". Now everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

is there enough width for `body` or any parent tags, or browser window?
you may wanted this,

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnSei.png

but if there no enough width it could displayed like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NeXca.png

Answer (score 0):

If you don't give the .loga div the style inline-block for other reasons than the question, just remove it. The default display property is block. 
They are already inline. But they have to drop to the second line because of the line width. So all you have to do is enlarge the .yoga by giving it a     width:100%  or width:500px etc...

Answer (score 0):

Images default display properties - **inline-block**.

```
img {
   display: inline-block; 
}
```

Try it:

```
.loga {
    display: block;
    width: 900 px;
}
```